# Formatting Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel

How does one manipulate the format of the excel sheet using python?

My code currently is taking data from several spreadsheets and is pulling the data I want from these sheets into a single workbook. I want the formatting of the workbook to be consistent, because every iteration of the code just saves over the previously made one.

example I want the Cell A1 to be extended and background of the cell to be blue, but I need A2 background to be red

Comment: hello and welcome.  please akcnowledge the "right" way to ask questions. see, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . BTW, what have you tried out so far? can you show your code? maybe also show your spreadsheet? pandas allows excel formatting, (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#excel-output-for-styled-dataframes) and there are several other libraries around also doing the job, e.g. xlsxwriter (http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Which `xlsx module` you are using?